# How can i count all azure EventHub events of the current day using StreamAnalitics each 5 minutes?

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I need to count all events collected during the current day, from 0:00 to 23:59 utc time each five minutes.

I'm using a stream analytics service withe the current query:

```
SELECT Cast(pid as bigint) as PublisherID,Cast(cid as bigint) as   CampaignID, Count(*) as Count
 INTO
    [SQLTableClicks]
FROM
    [Clicks]
GROUP BY pid,cid, TumblingWindow(Day,1)
```

it works but it only collect data once a day and  i need to update the info each five minutes.

Comment: So, am I correct to say you want to start with 0 events at 00:00 each day and every five minutes you want the total count so far?

Comment: Yes, you got the point.

Answer (score 0):

I think hopping window is what you need, it will give you result every 5 minutes, but looking a day back.

Try something like this (I didn't run it, but should give you an idea):

```
With data as
(
    SELECT 
        Cast(pid as bigint) as PublisherID,
        Cast(cid as bigint) as CampaignID,
        Count(*) as Count,
        System.TimeStamp as Time
    FROM
        [Clicks]
)

SELECT PublisherID, CampaignID, Count
INTO
    [SQLTableClicks]
FROM
    [data]
WHERE (DAY(System.TimeStamp) == Day(Time))
GROUP BY pid,cid, HoppingWindow(Duration(day, 1), Hop(minute, 5))
```

Comment: System.TimeStamp can be used only in Select. Is this correct? WHERE (DAY = Day(Time))

Comment: Not sure...
If so -
SELECT PublisherID, CampaignID, Count, DAY(System.TimeStamp) as WindowCloseDay

and
WHERE (WindowCloseDay == Day(Time))

Comment: System.TimeStamp get the insert time of the event not the current time.